# Use values from one vector to change values in another vector in R (for loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I need to change certain values in one vector depending on what the values are in the same places on in another vector. Below are my vectors:

```
r <- (1:20)
a <- c(54,54,54,54,55,55,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,56,57)
```

Basically if any of the values in 'a' are greater than or equal to and less than 20 (so any value in a that is 0-20) I want to change that value in 'r' to be itself -1. If the value in 'a' is greater than 20 or less than 0, then I want its value in 'r' to remain the same. So for the 8th spot in 'a' the value is 0 which is greater than/equal to 0 and less than 20 so I want the 8th spot in 'r' (has a value of 8) subtract by 1 (so now its value will be 7). But for the first spot in 'a', the value is 54 which is greater than 20 so the 1st value in r will remain the same. I assumed I needed to write a for loop for this and I started to but it's not doing what I need it to do. This is what I have so far.

```
for(i in a){
  if (i >= 0 && i < 20){
    r[i] = r[i]-1
  } else {
    r[i] = r[i]
  }
}
```

When I run this code it returns r as

```
[1] -4  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[32] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

How can I get it to return the correct result which should look like this:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for those who have answered so far! I also just realized a potential problem. These vectors are just snippets of data I'm actually currently working with. 'r' vector is actually hour of day (so 0 through 23 repeating with some hours missing here and there) and repeats for about 3 months. If using this code for an hour 0 for example, subtracting 1 from it would make the hour -1 but I would want it to be hour 23 or whatever hour number is before it. Would the solutions you all posted below still apply? Please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would help,

```
r <- (1:20)
a <- c(54,54,54,54,55,55,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,56,57)

r[a >= 0 & a < 20] <- r[a >= 0 & a < 20] - 1

# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
```

You don't need a loop here the above answer is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the sequence

```
for(i in seq_along(a)) if(a[i] >=0 && a[i] < 20) r[i] <- r[i] -1 
r
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
```

instead of the values of 'a' because `r[54]` doesn't exist and assigning on that element results in `NA`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
r - (a >= 0 & a < 20) 

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a compact base R solution is to use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(a>=0 & a< 20,r-1,r)
```

which gives

```
> ifelse(a>=0 & a< 20,r-1,r)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20
```